# Undefined property in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on an array of array, and I want to test each first value but all what I get is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
Help please!

```
 function getManualDesactivation(data){

var tab=[];
var l=data.length ; 
var listeService= getCategorie(data);
var resultat=[];

for(var i=0; i<l;i++){
        if (data[i][1] == "DESACTIVATION") {
            var subtab=[];
            subtab.push(data[i][0]);
            subtab.push(data[i][2]);
        tab.push(subtab);


        }       
}

if (tab.length > 1) {
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listeService.length; i++) {

        if (listeService[i] == tab[j][0]) {<---- here is the exception
            resultat.push(tab[j][1]);

            j++;
        } else {

            resultat.push(0);
            j++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your issue?

Comment: What is the `data` variable containing and what is  `getCategorie(data)` returning? If one of those does not return the expected content then that is likely the error.

Comment: Probably *i* is bigger than *j*, so `j++` causes *j* to increment up to and beyond `tab.length`, so `tab[j]` returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

That error is caused by trying to access the 0 index of variable that does not exist.

To ensure that you are checking the index of a defined value, you can write:

```
    if (tab[j] && listeService[i] == tab[j][0]) {
        resultat.push(tab[j][1]);

        j++;
    } else {

        resultat.push(0);
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: I was going to write this